# .bat to .sh converting for SQL*Loader Start on UNIX PC

Tags: batch-file, converters, sh, sql-loader

I have a simple .bat file

```
@echo; set nls_lang=russian_cis.ru8pc866  
@echo off

SET NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=. '


sqlldr.exe userid=PRB/0611@TSESTDB control=control_file.ctl LOG=fdb_log.log errors=100

cmd
```

and i need to convert to .sh file for running on the UNIX based pc. 
I began to read "[BASH Programming - Introduction HOW-TO](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO.html#toc3)" (is it suitable for beginners?), but it is a episodical task and dead line comes.

Could anybody help me to convert file? Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1):

rewriting your script.

```
  #!/bin/bash

  # @echo; 
  # set nls_lang=russian_cis.ru8pc866 
  export NLS_LANG=russian_cis.ru8pc866

  # not needed @echo off

  # SET NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=. '
  export NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS='.'

  PATH="/path/to/sqlDir/install:${PATH}"
  # sqlldr.exe userid=PRB/0611@TSESTDB control=control_file.ctl LOG=fdb_log.log errors=100
  sqlldr userid=PRB/0611@TSESTDB control=control_file.ctl LOG=fdb_log.log errors=100

  # ? cmd
```

I've left your code in, but commented out (using the shell comment char '#'). The uncommented lines are the 'translation' of .bat syntax into Linux/Unix bash/shell syntax.

There some things above that you **may** need to fix:

1. You'll have to include the correct value in the resetting of PATH,
   note that the value there is strictly to illustrate the issue.
   `export` is used so that variables set in the current shell (the
   shell script) are visible to child processes that run from the shell
   script, in this case the important one being `sqlldr`
2. I'm not sure what values you really need assigned to
       `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS`. Note that by quoting with the single-quote
       char `'` available to the shell, you should get exactly the value
       used that you intended. If '*' or other reg-exp chars are used, this
       may cause problems.
3. You may find that `sqlldr.exe` has a different name altogether. The
       linux/unix convention for executable commands does not require the
       `.exe` extension, so I have used `sqlldr`. Just use the full name of
       the program you find in the installed directory.

The line with `#!/bin/bash` needs to be the first line in the file, with no leading spaces.

You'll also need to inform your OS that the script is intended to be executable. From a bash cmd line, IN the directory that contains this script, do

```
 chmod 755 mySQLLDR_runningScript
```

Finally, not sure why you have `cmd` at the end of your .bat file, to open a new window? You'll need to experiment on your system to find the correct cmd to do that. Maybe `xterm`.

I hope this helps.

Comment: i run                         'PATH="/opt/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/bin:${PATH}"         sqlldr userid=PRB/0611@TSESTDB control=control_file.ctl LOG=fdb_log.log errors=100'                                                                                                                                                    and result is sqlldr: command not found =(

Comment: please edit your question to include the output from `ls -l /opt/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/bin/*`. Good luck.